# html 5 DATE doesn't work in Windows Exploror and Firefox

Tags: php, html, date

i been working on ticker reservation system and i used date function in forms but , which works fine on chrome but does not work on windows explorer and Firefox. what should i do?

```
departure date: <input type="date" name="departuredate"> departure time : <input type="time" name="departuretime"> arrival date : <input type="date" name="arrivaldate"> arrival time : <input type="time" name="arrivaltime">
```

Comment: What date function? `type="date"` is not supported in FF for sure.

Comment: Show us your markup and explain _"doesn't work"_ in more detail, please.

Comment: departure date:     <input type="date" name="departuredate">
departure time :    <input type="time" name="departuretime">
arrival date :          <input type="date" name="arrivaldate">
arrival time :            <input type="time" name="arrivaltime">

Comment: if its HTML5, IE wont work. You need a 3rd party library for this

Comment: Which one is the best can you tell me the code ? actually i'm new to it so i dont really know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a third party date picker plugin which works on almost all browsers like JQuery UI Datepicker:

See the demo below:

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

**How to use**

In the `<head> </head>` tags of your page insert the following lines:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now create an input element which will be used as the datepicker like below:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Now before closing the body tag (`</body>`) copy the following lines:

```
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
```

Or if you want you can copy these lines in the head tags as well, but I would recommend you put them here.

Comment: do i need to have jquery installed on my computer?

Comment: ...or the OP could show us the markup and explain the issue before including a bunch of bloated (and perhaps unnecessary) frameworks?

Comment: @Rizwan No you do not need to install JQuery on you computer to run it on your web page. simply use the code provided on their site or even in the code example I gave you and you are good to go.

Comment: how to embed the code in my sign up page, because i need to have the value so i can pass to DB.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Firefox (desktop) not Internet Explorer implement any date/time input control. You can see this in the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility) table found at [`<input>` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

It probably wasn't a priority for either teams given how powerful an ubiquitous JavaScript selectors have become.